# SOAP web service in MVC - The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

We have a web service located at [website]/Api/HmlApi.svc/soap which normally works OK. Its not SSL.

In this particular site we can see the .svc page fine in a browser, but the client application attempting to access this service gets a http 404 error. Endpoint not found.

The website has config as follows.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<!--Set up the service-->
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior" name="HmlApi">        
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VLSCore2.Interfaces.IHmlApi" />
  </service>
</services>
<!--Define the behaviours-->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The log in the website has the following error:

```
/Api/Hmlapi.svc/soap - The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController
```

This to me points to the url being right - we are hitting the site, we can get to the svc but somehow it does not route to the soap endpoint as setup as normal in the config above.

Any ideas to why in the case of this one site it might not work? Anything else we can check?

Comment: Does your routing handle the `.` in your URL?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly configured the WebApi route config. You may have them in the Global.asax.cs or if you are in a MVC4 or MVC5 project, in the App_Start folder, WebApiConfig.cs.

If you have the routes configured correctly, then are you putting the service configuration in the correct configuration file?

Greetings!